# receive email address and attachment not get properly in phpmailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I want to send email with attachment in php. But receive email address and attachment not get properly in my code. When I give the email address manually email sending successful though email sending successful attachment not goes to receive end properly.

```
    <form action="sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                            <h1 class="cta-title">Its a Call To Action</h1>
                            <div class="cta-desc">
                                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['catogary'];?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['company_name'];?>' readonly style="width:    75%"><br><br>
                                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['location'];?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['qulification'];?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['catogary'];?>' readonly style="width: 75%"><br><br>
                                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['indate'];?>' readonly style="width: 37.5%">&nbsp;
                                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['expdate'];?>' readonly style="width: 37.5%">
                                <input type="text" value='<?= $row['email'];?>' ><br>
                                <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file" class="text-center center-block well well-sm">
                                <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Apply">
                            </div>
                            </form>
```

sendemail.php

```
    <?php
    $email2=$_POST['email'];
    require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    //PHPMailer Object
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "getinternshipuwu@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "uwucst14xxxx";
$mail->SetFrom("getinternshipuwu@gmail.com");
$mail->FromName = "Internship Management";

//To address and name
$mail->addAddress($email2);
//$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com"); //Recipient name is optional

//Address to which recipient will reply
$mail->addReplyTo("getinternshipuwu@gmail.com", "Reply");

//CC and BCC
//$mail->addCC("CC");
//$mail->addCC("CC");
//$mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'CV for internship Vacancy';
$mail->Body =  "Attached";
//$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";
//$mail->AddAttachment($target_path,$CV);
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) && $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
}

if(!$mail->send())
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    //echo 'Not sent: <pre>'.print_r(error_get_last(), true).'</pre>';

}
else
{
    //echo "Message has been sent successfully";
    echo 'Successfully Applied for vacancy';
}

//**end of send e-mail**
?>
```

error is:

```
    Undefined index: email in /storage/h7/602/1448602/public_html/sendemail.php on line 2
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: sorry for the mistake.now check

Comment: Your form tag is missing attribute method="post" and ive remove the mysql tag because no mysql is been used in this code or question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file sendemail.php you are using

```
   <?php
    $email2=$_POST['email'];
```

this is your form tag.

```
<form action="sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

This is sending the form with HTTP method GET but it needs to be POST.
So you need to add attribute method="post" in the form tag like so

```
<form action="sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

You fix the error

```
Undefined index: email in /storage/h7/602/1448602/public_html/sendemail.php on line 2
```

By changing this line

```
<input type="text" value='<?= $row['email'];?>' ><br>
```

To

```
<input type="text" name="email" value='<?= $row['email'];?>' ><br>
```

Comment: i tried this friend but result is same

Comment: @Danith Kumarasinghe ive editted the answer after you included the error..

Comment: thank you @Raymonnd Nijiland...that error is coorect now.can u guide me to succefuly attach the attachment